# Making multiple arrays using a for loop

Tags: php

I have a problem regarding a small PHP project that I am working on, I am trying to create a few arrays using a for loop, these arrays should have different names, here is the code where the problem is:

```
<?php
$cle="briques";
$clesplit=str_split($cle);
$longcle=count($clesplit);
for($i=1;$i<=$longcle;$i++){
$array'$i'=array();
}
?>
```

the result I want is arrays with different names like:

```
array1
array2
arrya3
.
.
.etc
```

Comment: How exactly are you creating the array? What does the arrays have to do with the string `$cle`? Also what should be the expected result?

Comment: the rusult i want is arrays with diffrent names like:

array1 array2 arrya3 . . .etc

im trying to create a number of arrays equal  to the number of the letters in $cle

Comment: Instead of creating arrays with different names - use __multidimensional__ array.

Comment: Multidimentional array?

Comment: Multi = An array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap them in `{}`:

```
${"array" . $i} = array(); // e.g. array1, array2, etc...
```

But, as good practice, you should use a **multidimensional array** instead like so:

```
$array[i] = array(); // e.g. array[1], array[2], etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
<?php
    $cle="briques";
    $clesplit=str_split($cle);
    foreach($clesplit as $value){
        $n = "array".$value;
        $$n = <some value you desire>
    }
?>
```

What happens here is, you take the content from `$n` and set it to a variable
[Check this for more info](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: I have tried this code,

<?php

$cle="briques";
$clesplit=str_split($cle);
$longcle=count($clesplit);
for($i=0;$i<=$longcle;$i++){
 ${"array".$i}=array($clesplit[$i]);
 
 
} ?>

i just recieved a : Undefined offset: 7 in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9  error

Comment: im just triying to create 7 arrays, (in this case '7' is the nubmer of letters on $cle), and fill each array with a letter from $cle, so in this case $cle = "briques" so the first array should have the letter 'b', the second array should have the letter 'r' and so on, not to forget that each array should have the name array1 , array 2 , .. etc
i got the same error when using :
$array[i] = array();